# Match this string with a strong RegEx?

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I need to create a pattern for this string. This should be somewhat easy but I can't make a regex that would only include this string as a match. Thanks in advance!

Rule ^/sampleForExample/f/default.htm$ %{SCHEME}://www${TIER}.someadress.com/something/ [F=200]

Rule ^/notTheSameSample/something/default.htm$ %{SCHEME}://www${TIER}.someaddress.com/something/educators/ [F=200]

Comment: Please, clarify your question. It is rather confusing with special symbols. What do you have and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to match **notTheSameSample** and **something**?

The regex should work. :)

\w  [a-zA-Z0-9]

```
\/[\w]+\/[\w]+\/default\.htm\$[\w\/\s\.\{\}:%]+\$[\w\/\s\.\{\}:%]+\[F\=200\]$
```